# Running a Jar from another Jar doesn't work when exported

Tags: java, jar

I've been reading about the subject for a few hours:

What I'd like to do (and succeeded to do) is to run a runnable jar from my code, the thing is, when I export the code into a runnable jar, then it stops working.

The method that works from my compiler is :

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "JAR I'M LOADING");
pb.start
```

This is what I've tried :

I've created a packet with the jar that I wanna run, and I created a static JarLoader class where I do :

```
public class JarLoader {

    static JarLoader jl = new JarLoader();

    public static ProcessBuilder loadJar(){
        return new  ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", jl.getClass().getResource("JAR I'M TRYING TO LOAD").toString());

}
```

And of course I switched the method that is runs the jar to :

```
ProcessBuilder pb = JarLoader.loadJar();
pb.start();
```

This technique worked very well with other type of resources, such as images, but it doesn't work with the jar.

Am I missing something ? (and  yes, I did add the folder containing the Jar and the JarLoader to the project's source)

Comment: The jar you're loading is inside another jar?

Comment: Yes it is, I have this university project where I need to load one project I made from another one, both of which are runnable jars

Comment: Extract the jar file to the disk first.  Or include the first Jar as a library to the second and simple load it's classes directly...

Comment: Both project run a swing GUI, so I'd like each of them to run on a different jvm, if possible, that's why I run one jar from the other one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique you're currently using allows you to get to a resource that's already packed inside your JAR file. But these resources are coherent only within the application, and not from outside it.

When you execute your JAR file using `java -jar ...`, that's an external application being executed, and it won't understand how to retrieve a JAR from inside another JAR. You will need to write it temporarily to disk, and then run the temporary JAR file.

You need to:

1. Open the resource as a stream.
2. Use [`Files.createTempFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29) to create a temporary JAR file somewhere.
3. Use [`Files.copy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) to copy from the resource stream to the temporary file.
4. Use [`File.deleteOnExit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit%28%29) to make sure that the temporary file will get cleaned up when the main (host) application terminates.
5. Execute the temporary file with `java -jar tempfile.jar` or whatever you called it.

Comment: Could you link to some documentation explaining how temporarily write the jar to the disk? is it done with IOstreams ?